# How can it be that different permissions apply using SFTP-client vs. SSHFS?

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, nas, sftp

## Setup SFTP+SSHFS

I have some Synology NAS configured to be able to use SFTP and SSHFS with some special user. It's important to note that this user is not `root`, but some different one. While I'm able to use plain SSH as `root` with a key pair, the NAS itself does not allow `root` to use SFTP at all. So I needed to create a different user, allow to use SFTP at all for that etc. That application level permissions stuff is simply not possible for `root`, so SFTP for that simply can't work.

This works fine in general, I can access directories using plain SFTP by some special client and SSHFS using Linux defaults from two different hosts.

## Setup network

Not sure if it's important as well, but the SFTP-client is part of the same private network like the NAS. When I'm using plain SFTP, I'm first creating some OVPN-tunnel to the same private network.

OTOH, this is not the case with SSHFS. The client which needs to use SSHFS uses SSHS's `JumpHost` instead to first create a connection to the firewall in front of the NAS-network and that firewall then forwards access to the NAS itself.

While that is a bit different between both use cases, I did not enable any IP-filtering or alike on the NAS! Though, there might be something I missed either in its web-UI or SSH's configs files.

## Problem

Some of the files I need to read using SSHFS are backups from some systems, owned by `root` and the permissions are so that only `root` can read those files at all. When my specially created SFTP-user was only a member of the built-in group `users`, it was NOT able to access those files at all, neither using the plain SFTP-client nor SSHFS. Which makes somewhat sense.

OTOH, and that is where things become interesting, after I added that user to the built-in group `administrators`, I was able to read all `root`-exclusive files instantly, but ONLY with the plain SFTP-client. Access tot he files is still denied when trying to read those with SSHFS.

But one thing even changed for SSHFS: `root`-exclusive directories can be browsed as well! It seems that access is only forbidden when actually trying to read the files.

## Thoughts

As SFTP-client and SSHFS use the same underlying protocol SFTP, from the perspective of the NAS the individual client used shouldn't make any difference. The only things which might make a difference are e.g. options provided to SFTP, the user with which authenticates happens etc. The SFTP-client is not able to forward any options and looking at the debug logs of SSHFS, really the same user like with the SFTP-client is used.

## Observations

It might be that SFTP is configured specially by default by the NAS already: When reading symlinks either using SFTP-client or SSHFS those seems to always be resolved on the NAS already. I get a lot of `File not found`-type of errors in the logs and mentions of `readlink`. From my understanding this shouldn't be the case by default unless e.g. `follow_symlinks` is forwarded by SSHFS, which is NOT the case for me!

## Questions

Any idea where the difference between SSHFS and the SFTP-client might come from?

Any idea where I could look at if the SSH `JumpHost` makes some difference?

**Thanks!**

Comment: **Speculating wildly** I wonder if sshfs might be using some scp/ssh symantics for faster speed and being restricted because PermitRootLogin is set to no, while sftp does not suffer this limitation?

Comment: I'm not logging in as `root`, the NAS doesn't allow that access for SFTP at all. Though, `sshd_config` contains `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` and I'm able to login with plain SSH as `root` and key pairs successfully. It's only not allowed for SFTP, which is why I was so happy that my user can access `root`-only files if it's member of the internal `administrators`-group. But only when using SFTP-client, not SSHFS for some reason.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with IP-based permissions or alike, but can't find anything configured like that. Access using the SFTP-client is from a client which is part of the same internal network like the NAS using some OVPN-tunnel. SSHFS is used by a client which uses SSH's `JumpHost` to first access the firewall of that network and that forwards access to the NAS.

Comment: What is the exact owner:group and mode of those files?

Comment: They are simply root-exclusive: `16175 4 -rw------- 1 root root 3239 Jul 12  2018 id_rsa`